# unable to get the notification when the messsage arrives from gcm android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, push, google-cloud-messaging

Example: In my application I have client,distributors and server.client ask questions to server and server will reply for that question via Gcm push notification.I have implemented this by googling it and push notification tutorials.

And my issue is, if I send a question from client,it gets displayed in server by parsing the link but I'm not getting the push notification. any one help me with this.I don't know where I have done mistake. Any suggestion to implement this functionality via push notification. server side script is write in php

I have posted the server part code...here only i want the push notification

```
my GCM class

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService
{

    private static final String TAG = "GCM Tutorial::Service";

    // Use your PROJECT ID from Google API into SENDER_ID
    public static final String SENDER_ID = "projectid";
    //SharedPreferences prefs;
    //DbHelper db;
    String xx = "";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

        //prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
        //prefsEditor.putString("registrationid", registrationId);
        //prefsEditor.commit();

        Log.i(TAG, "onRegistered: registrationId=" + registrationId);
        xx = registrationId;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), xx, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("Register : "+registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onUnregistered: registrationId=" + registrationId);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {
        //db = new DbHelper(context);
        //db.openToWrite();
        String message;
        // Message from PHP server
        message = data.getStringExtra("message");
        // Open a new activity called GCMMessageView
        //db.insertmessage(message);
        System.out.println("inside gcm class");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        // Pass data to the new activity
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        // Starts the activity on notification click
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Create the notification with a notification builder
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle("New message")
                .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .getNotification();
        // Remove the notification on click
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.sound = 
                RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);

        {
            // Wake Android Device when notification received
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            final PowerManager.WakeLock mWakelock = pm.newWakeLock(
                    PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "GCM_PUSH");
            mWakelock.acquire();

            // Timer before putting Android Device to sleep mode.
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    mWakelock.release();
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(task, 5000);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onError: errorId=" + errorId);
    }

}
```

question class

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class prompt extends Activity 
{
    Button prompt_ok,prompt_cancel;

    private static final String url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";

    private static final String url1="&sensor=false"; 

    EditText zip,noofsup;

    JSONArray results;

    JSONObject geometry,location;

    String latt,lngg,ques;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent in=getIntent();

        ques=in.getStringExtra("questionfornext");

        setContentView(R.layout.prompt);

        zip=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.zipcode);

        noofsup=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.noofsupplier);      

    }

    public void onClick(View view)

    {

    String zipcode=zip.getText().toString();

    String finalurl=url+zipcode+url1;

    new GetData().execute();

    new GetRegister().execute();

    new GetQuestion().execute();

    Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

    startActivity(in);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onCancel(View v)

    {

        Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

        startActivity(in);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>

    {

        String status;

        String zipcode=zip.getText().toString();

        String finalurl=url+zipcode+url1;

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {

            super.onPreExecute();
         // Showing progress dialog
        }


        @Override

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
        {

            // Creating service handler class instance

            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(finalurl, ServiceHandler.GET);


            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);


            if (jsonStr != null)
            {

                try 
                {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    status=jsonObj.getString("status");

                    System.out.println("status"+status);

                    results=jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

                    for(int j=0;j==0;j++)

                    {
                        JSONObject c=results.getJSONObject(0);

                        geometry=c.getJSONObject("geometry");

                        JSONObject ob=geometry.getJSONObject("location");

                        latt=ob.getString("lat");

                        lngg=ob.getString("lng");

                        // String latt=location.getString("lat");

                        //String lngg=location.getString("lng");
                        System.out.println("latt"+latt);

                        System.out.println("lng"+lngg);

                    }               

                }

                catch (JSONException e) 
                {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
            else 
            {

                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");

            }

            return null;


        }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {

            super.onPostExecute(result);


            if(status.equals("OK"))

            {

             new GetRegister().execute();

             //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            else

            {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Valid ZIP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }

    }

    private class GetRegister extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>

    {

        //String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);


        String weburl="register url ";//if we ask question it will automatically register
        String weburl1="&latitude=";

        String weburl2="&longtitude=";

        String weburl3="&type=Android&author=Jers&Submit=submit";

        String code,msg;

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {

            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)

        {


            ServiceHandler sh=new ServiceHandler();

            String finalweburl=weburl+MainActivity.androidId+weburl1+latt+weburl2+lngg+weburl3;

            System.out.println("new final web url----////"+finalweburl);

            String str=sh.makeServiceCall(finalweburl,ServiceHandler.GET);

            if(str!=null)
            {

                try

                {

                    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(str);

                    code=obj.getString("code");

                    msg=obj.getString("msg");

                    System.out.println("jewellery  id-----"+MainActivity.androidId);

                    System.out.println("code-----"+code);

                }
                catch(JSONException e)

                {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

            else

            {

                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");

            }

            return null;   

        }
   @Override

   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
   {

       super.onPostExecute(result);

       if(code.equals("1"))
        {

           new GetQuestion().execute();

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

       else

       {

           //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NOT a question", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }


   }

    }

    private class GetQuestion extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        EditText question1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.question);

        String success,msg1;

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
                super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)

        {

            String noofsupplier=noofsup.getText().toString();

            ServiceHandler sh=new ServiceHandler();

            String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);

            String url="request url for distributor ";

            String url1="&question=";

            String url2="&no_of_suppliers=";

            String finalurlq1=url+android_id+url1+ques+url2+noofsupplier;

            String finalurlq=new String(finalurlq1.replaceAll(" ","%20"));

            System.out.println(finalurlq);

            System.out.println("question---->"+ques);

            String str1=sh.makeServiceCall(finalurlq,ServiceHandler.GET);

            if(str1!=null)

            {

                try

                {

                    JSONObject ob=new JSONObject(str1);

                    JSONObject ob1=ob.getJSONObject("response");

                    success=ob1.getString("success");

                    msg1=ob1.getString("msg");

                    System.out.println("success---->"+success);

                    System.out.println("msg----->"+msg1);

                }
                catch(JSONException e)

                {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

            else

            {
            }

            return null;
       }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Dismiss the progress dialog

            // if (pDialog.isShowing())

            //   pDialog.dismiss();


            /* * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView**/


            if(success.equals("1"))

            {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Question is Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            else

            {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Question not registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Since you didn't include any code, how can we know where you made a mistake?

Comment: let me know the code part like gcmclass etc., that you want to check because i don't know which one your  are asking because I have written it in three application named consumer,distributor and server.